# Geração de objetos com um determinado valor dentro de uma distribuição definida

Tags: java

Estou com uma dificuldade para criar objetivos relacionado a percentagem.

O que desejo fazer, é um método que gere objetos, todos os objetos possuem apenas um atributo.

Preciso que 20% dos objetos sejam gerados com esse atributo tendo como valor 1 e os outros tendo como valor 2, porém, preciso disso de um modo que na minha `ArrayQueue` os com valor 1 e 2 não fiquem necessariamente posicionados um do lado do outro.

Comment: 20% de forma determinística ou aleatória?

Comment: determinística!

Comment: "não fiquem necessariamente posicionados um do lado do outro" por acaso significa adicionar os objetos a um array e embaralhá-los (`Collections.shuffle()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sua dificuldade é criar os objetos, tente isso:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Porcentagem {
    private final int valor;

    public Porcentagem(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Porcentagem> q = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            q.add(new Porcentagem(i % 5 == 0 ? 1 : 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Basicamente, este algoritmo repetidamente insere um elemento com valor 1 seguido de quatro elementos com valor 2. Assim, ele garante uma ordem determinística aonde os 1s não estarão do lado uns dos outros. Se não é isso o que você quer, por favor explique melhor.

Observação: Não há classe `ArrayQueue` no java. Só achei `ArrayList` e `ArrayDeque`. Usei `ArrayList` no código acima, mas você pode usar a que achar melhor.